# ASP.NET MVC3 - receiving the "No overload for method 'BeginForm' takes 6 arguments" error message

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

My controller has two following methods...

```
public FileResult GetImage(int id)
    {
     // something
    }
    public FileResult GetImageTwo(int id)
    {
     // something   
    }
```

Create.cshtml as the following code...

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "ProductCategory", "GetImage", 
 "GetImageTwo",  FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" 
}))
```

> Update

So the answer is it can't be done like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify which controller action you are going to post to and use the proper overload:

```
                         action      controller            method                htmlAttributes
                            ↓             ↓                   ↓                        ↓
@using (Html.BeginForm("GetImage", "ProductCategory", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    //somecode
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That has nothing to do with routes. Error is simple, you are calling `Html.BeginForm` overload that does not exists. In other words, there's no method like `Html.BeginForm` which would take 6 arguments. If you update your question to show what are you trying to achieve, maybe stack could help you

Comment: I have updated with a lot of information, if you want to have a look?